# can i build a cheap linear actuator

Tags: raspbian, gpio, python, pi-2

*[Cross-posted to [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/255493/52138).]*

I need a linear actuator for my IOT project but how do i make one and how do i use python to control it? i saw videos of people making it with glue sticks and servos but i don't think it will be effective.
[image]

And i am making a auto feeder so any actuator that open and close it is ok.

Comment: That's gotta be a pretty high torque, not-your-average servo and/or a lot of grease is involved in the glue stick because generally they stick at the drop of a hat; I have a continuous rotation [FS5103R](http://www.feetechrc.com/product/analog-servo/3kg-cm-360-degree-continuous-rotation-servo-fs5103r/) about that size and there's no way I'd bother trying that with it -- it will stall on, e.g., the plastic tip of a small pull tie.  It may be capable of rotating weight, but if there is the slightest physical resistance forget it (I dunno physics but i.e., "3 kg @ 1 cm" = practically nothing).

Comment: So what should i do ? Is there a effective instead of using glue sticks and servos ?

Comment: I'm just pointing this out so you don't rush out and buy something that looks like that -- I think the problem will be that even if the actuator isn't applying much force, it will take barely anything to produce too much friction in the screw threads.  I'm a total ignoramus regarding robotic-y stuff, but I would look into a stepper motor, and/or do some research about torque requirements (and how finely you can control the motor's rotation -- my continuous rotation servo is fairly fine grained but the slowest speed amounts to I think about 1 turn in 10 seconds).

Comment: Another issue is you may need something like a *rotary encoder* if you need to keep track of the exact position, and those won't work with servos (there are some "force feedback" servos that give position but I think they are the standard 180° type, not continuous); I have a zany 8 point led & light sensitive resistor rig that works but it would be really zany in this context.  As in, there are 8 leds positioned in a circle and a light sensitive resistor in a skinny tube which rotates (which is an analog sensor, so you'd need yet more hardware, and means there's something wired rotating, etc).

Comment: Again, I don't have much experience with this stuff but those are some issues that jump out at me.  I know some stepper motors can include a magnetic hall sensor type encoder but I think this is only good for counting rotations, not giving an exact position, so you need to think about whether that is important.  Also, different rotary encoders have different precision in this regard.

Comment: Since these diy linear actuators have so many issues do i have to buy a linear actuators or is there any effective and cost-effective way to open and close my feeder ?

Comment: It's up to you to weigh the pros and cons with stuff, e.g., cost of an actuator vs. time required to DIY.  With regard to the latter, it may not be as simple as it first appears particularly if you need to know "where is the actuator now"?  I guess if it's controlling two positions (open and shut) and the motor/servo stalls when it reaches either position you could just decide it takes about 3 seconds and turn it on for that long.

Comment: I asked the same question in the electronics forum they told that i could use some kind of flaps but id don't know what it is. Is it an effective way to control my bird feeder?

Comment: I believe the "flap" would be the butterfly valve [pictured here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotary_actuator).  I'd look into that RC thing ("linear servo") from the [cross-post](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/255493/52138) (I've added that to your question as a courtesy to others).  The use of gears is a very good idea as is getting something build as a package like that; it doesn't look like it could be more than $20.

Comment: So how do i use these gears ?

Comment: I meant the gearing that's build into that linear servo thing -- the servo has a little gear whereas the actuator screw has a big one, so each complete revolution of the servo represents only a fraction of a revolution for the actuator screw, reducing the amount of torque required.  If you don't understand gears but you've ridden a bike before, think for a few minutes about the fact that the low gears on the front (pedal axle) are *smaller*, whereas the low gears on the back (wheel axle) are *bigger*.

Comment: You can buy little plastic gears like that but again, I think you are much better off getting a package device designed by some engineer.   I notice googling around you can get "pico linear servos" for ~$15 USD from robotics places with 2cm of travel.  That sounds to me like something which will translate the "3kg @ 1cm" (the distance there is unrelated) stall torque into something that can actually apply a few pounds of pressure, which is probably what you need to close the hopper (or open it if you make it spring loaded)

Comment: ...And you could run a servo like that straight from the pi (make sure it is okay w/ 5V, the "VS-19" one I'm looking at seems to be 3.7V exactly, no range).

Comment: So how do i use the vs 19 linear servo in my bird feeder? it isn't very straightforward.

Comment: It has an actuator screw, i.e., it seems to me it's a form of "linear actuator".  Looking around again I guess there aren't very many such things -- but [here's a 5V to 3.7V adapter made for it](http://www.robotshop.com/ca/en/solarbotics-pico-linear-servo-voltage-adapter-kit.html), that's only $2, $13 for the VS-19 then shipping...so it depends whether that adds up to something worth the gamble.  It only moves less than an inch and one of the customer reviews there says don't expect it move more than 150g (5.4 oz).  So a pretty small bird feeder...

Comment: @goldilocks I think i have an idea which is cost-effective. Its hard to explain without animated pictures but i need a 360 rotation servo so can you tell me which one is best for me(i never bought servos). I need a small one with perfect precision with a long shaft.

Comment: I'm no expert on the topic; you should ask about servos on our larger sibling site, [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/).  My initial comment was just a warning that the thing in the picture probably won't be good for much if you can get it to work at all. **You also need be clear about *exactly* what you want to do.** Saying "it's for a bird feeder" is totally ambiguous since a bird feeder may vary greatly in size.  Saying "I need a 360 servo" is ambiguous along the same lines since this also does not deal with the issue of size and **the amount of force involved**.

Comment: I'm going to build something similar to butterfly valve with a 360servo or dc anything that has perfect precision. And i am pretty sure it is more effective than a linear actuator but i just know what king of motor i should use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As to how to make one, that's probably best left to [electronics.stackexchange.com.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) To control it, you'll want a **relay board**. This will allow you to switch large voltages and currents (like the ones you'll need for a linear actuator) on and off when the Raspberry Pi can't provide them.
The details will depend on the actuator (which I'm not an expert on) but you'll need to connect the actuator to a voltage source with enough current to drive it, and put some part of the circuit through the relay pins. Then connect the control pin of the relay to GPIO (and make sure the grounds are connected together) and use Python (or another language with a GPIO library) to change the state of the relay

Let me know if anything needs clarifying :)

Comment: how do i control my actuator using a relay board ? what python library should i use? is there anything that i should learn to use a relay board?  Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @TechDinoKing there are lots of types of linear actuators, and motors that drive them. If I understand correctly, you just need to work out for **your type of motor** how to drive it. With most motors a relay should be fine, _stepper_ motors are the exception and need a _stepper motor driver_. Once you've got more details, the programming's the easy part and normally consists of outputting HIGH and LOW to the relay/stepper driver. You'll find a wider community on Electronics, I'd recommend breaking your question down and posting it there.

Answer (score 1):

[image: www.active-robots.com]

You can buy [linear actuators](http://www.active-robots.com/brands/firgelli/rc-linear-servo) that are better quality than glue sticks and servos but they are expensive.

To [control the RC servo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N5QmZ92uvUo), the motor part of the linear actuator you need to generate PWM.  You can [use Python to do this](https://github.com/aboudou/pizypwmhttp://mad-science.wonderhowto.com/how-to/build-vacation-pet-feeder-with-diy-linear-actuator-0134695/)

Comment: But this doesn't look like an actuator that open and close my feeder. How should i use this servo ?

Comment: Yes you are correct the commercial servos do not look like glue sticks..sorry lol..:)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-do1gOE5DZ8 shows the size of the servo, it is easy to fit into project that you are trying to do.  http://mad-science.wonderhowto.com/how-to/build-vacation-pet-feeder-with-diy-linear-actuator-0134695/

Comment: Thanks... Also could you please help me with another part of my project...I am going to build something similar to a butterfly valve pictured [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Schwenkantrieb_auf_klappe.jpg)here[link].and i need and 360 degree servo with a long shaft. Can you tell which one is best for the project i am doing(i never bought servos). Thanks